# How to display the table in sqlite3 by creating the table via Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I just used the Pycharm and the package Sqlite3 to generate a table in sqlite3. Meanwhile, I am using SqliteStudio to visualize the relationship between databases and tables. However, the table created from Pycharm cannot be seen in SqliteStudio. Any idea how can I achieve it?

here is the code:

```
import sqlite3


def conSqlite():
  conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\jet.cai\Documents\Logsitic.db')

  conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE CNAME
  (ID INT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
  NAME            TEXT NOT NULL,
  AGE             TEXT NOT NULL)''')

  print('Done')

  cursor = conn.execute("select id from cname")
  for row in cursor:
      print('ID = ', row[0], 'NAME = ', row[1], 'AGE = ', row[2] )


  conSqlite()
```

Comment: You can use another app to see what is in your database (I personnally use Spatialite)

Comment: so there is no way to display the table via SQLite huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay with python, you may find interesting to use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\jet.cai\Documents\Logsitic.db')
df = pd.read_sql_query("select id from cname", con)
print(df)
```

Comment: Oh yes, also forgot this package, pandas will do me the favor when checking the data in Python of course, Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer as accepted if this has resolved your problem ;-)

Comment: let me check the Spatialite first, I wanna a GUI way to demonstrate what has been created, SQLite is obviously out of the way. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, I use Spatialite for that same purpose (particularly when when I'm not sure what occured in my database...) !

Comment: Hola, sir, yes you are absolutely right, spatialite is finely able to do me the favor! Thanks again.